# 9-Patch image is not showing content padding as defined

Tags: android, nine-patch

9 patch image with content padding:
[image: 9 patch image]

**but on device content padding is not appearing as defined**

[image: how this image is showing on real device its not showing padding as defined]

Comment: Explain your question CLEARLY, so that we can help you. What do u mean by "device content padding isnt appearing"?

Comment: i want my content to be appear in white area but its showing soo much padding .....i have defined content padding but its not showing as defined ......

Comment: Could that maybe you have more than one of this 9-patch at you drawable resources? Your device could be picking up the wrong one...

Comment: no i have only one image that is hdpi....